# SQL Query fine in phpMyAdmin, does not work in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Places.ID), Places.Name, PlacesToFoursq.FoursqCatID, Places.Latitude, Places.Longitude
FROM Places
LEFT JOIN PlacesToFoursq ON Places.ID = PlacesToFoursq.ID
WHERE FoursqCatID IS NULL 
OR FoursqCatID =  ''
```

Which works fine in phpMyAdmin. However when this is used through PHP:

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {}
```

I get no results. I have tried using escape characters with the single quotation marks (`FoursqCatID= \' \'` but that also appears not to solve the issue.

The `$sql` is stored as:

`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(Places.ID), Places.Name, PlacesToFoursq.FoursqCatID, Places.Latitude, Places.Longitude FROM Places LEFT JOIN PlacesToFoursq ON Places.ID=PlacesToFoursq.ID WHERE FoursqCatID IS NULL OR FoursqCatID=''";`

There is no error given, but `var_dump($row)` returns nothing.

Comment: What does mysli_error() say?

Comment: Show your query related code in php

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` and verify it looks like what you want.

Comment: how are you storing the query in the variable `$sql`

Comment: Are you sure the database connection is successfully established in `$con`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the connection with your database in your php file? And look that you have the right database selected.

Answer (score 0):

> WHERE FoursqCatID IS NULL OR FoursqCatID =  ''

Should be changed to:

> WHERE PlacesToFoursq.FoursqCatID IS NULL OR PlacesToFoursq.FoursqCatID =  ''